# How to add multiple lines after a specific pattern or line number in a linux file within python envirnoment

Tags: python, linux, sed

for executing below SED command in linux shell, I haven't problem. but for running it within python-2 environment, I've problem.

I want to add below lines after **href=part1** line in a HTML linux file.

```
CMDD = "sed -i '/href=part1/a \n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t</tr>' /root/var/www/html/start/index.html" %(logs[0], logs[1], logs[2], logs[3], logs[4], logs[5], logs[6], logs[7])

res = subprocess.Popen([CMDDD], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

print res
```

After run, I got below error:

> ('', "sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown command: `<'\n")

I haven' any problem within terminal (for example):

```
sed -i "/href=part1/a <tr>\n\t\t  <td>AliReza</td>\n\t\t <td>David</td>\n\t\t </tr>" tables.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the command a raw string by adding `r` to the start, like so

```
CMDD = r"sed -i '/href=part1/a \n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t</tr>' /root/var/www/html/start/index.html" %(logs[0], logs[1], logs[2], logs[3], logs[4], logs[5], logs[6], logs[7])
```

Remember python will convert `\n` to the literal line feed character (`\x0A`) in a non-raw string.

Comment: I already did it. and I got different error:  ('', "sed: can't read /root/var/www/html/start/index.html: No such file or directory\n").  Even I used // as Path instead of /.

Comment: Is there a file at `/root/var/www/html/start/index.html`?

Comment: Yes, the file isn't empty.

Comment: Well, sounds like a `sed` issue which is not my area of expertise. In any case, keep passing the raw string.

Comment: the problem was from Path. Also i forgot to use "r" as RAW before string. TNx u.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to POpen should be a list/tuple of the command itself and the params the command takes. In your case that means:

```
CMDD = [
    "sed",
    "-i",
    r"/href=part1/a \n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t  <td>%s</td>\n\t\t</tr>" % (logs[0], logs[1], logs[2], logs[3], logs[4], logs[5], logs[6], logs[7]),
    "/root/var/www/html/start/index.html",
]
res = subprocess.Popen(CMDD, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print res
```

As FHTMitchell says, you'll also need to use a raw string to prevent python escaping the special characters.

Comment: I got this error: ('', "Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...\n\n  -n, --quiet, --silent\n                 suppress automatic printing of pattern space\n  -e script, --expression=script\n

Comment: You could try printing CMDD to check it looks like what you'd expect, and has no obvious errors

Comment: sed -i "/href=part1/a 
  <tr>
...<skipped>....
    <td>2018-06-17</td>
    <td>70:79:90:41:62:50</td>
    <td>2018-06-17</td>
    <td>14:38:19</td>
    <td>15:39:29</td>
  </tr>" /root/var/www/html/start/index.html

Comment: There was an extra set of `[]`, maybe that was the issue.

Comment: With a different filename in CMDD (e.g. one that exists on my PC) the above runs sed for me.